# How to make the file.write() method in Python explicitly write the newline characters?

Tags: python, file-io, newline

I am trying to write text to an output file that explicitly shows all of the newline characters (`\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`,).  I am using Python 3 and Windows 7.  My thought was to do this by converting the strings that I am writing into bytes.

My code looks like this:

```
file_object = open(r'C:\Users\me\output.txt', 'wb')`
for line in lines:
    line = bytes(line, 'UTF-8')  
    print('Line: ', line)   #for debugging
    file_object.write(line)
file_object.close()
```

The `print(`) statement to standard output (my Windows terminal) is as I want it to be.  For example, one line looks like so, with the `\n` character visible.

`Line: b'<p class="byline">Foo C. Bar</p>\n'`

However, the `write()` method does not explicitly print any of the newline characters in my output.txt file.  Why does `write()` not explicitly show the newline characters in my output text file, even though I'm writing in bytes mode, but `print` does explicitly show the newline characters in the windows terminal?

Comment: you will need to escape it I think if you want to keep it visible. `\n` has a special meaning of newline and all print functions respect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Python does when writing strings or bytes to text or binary files:

- **Strings to a text file.** Directly written.
- **Bytes to a text file.** Writes the `repr`.
- **Strings to a binary file.** Throws an exception.
- **Bytes to a binary file.** Directly written.

You say that you get what you’re looking for when you write a `bytes` to standard out (a text file). That, with the pseudo-table above, suggests you might look into using `repr`. Specifically, if you’re looking for the output `b'<p class="byline">Foo C. Bar</p>\n'`, you’re looking for the `repr` of a `bytes` object.  If `line` was a `str` to start with and you don’t actually need that `b` at the beginning, you might instead be looking for the `repr` of the string, `'<p class="byline">Foo C. Bar</p>\n'`. If so, you could write it like this:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\me\output.txt', 'w') as file_object:
    for line in lines:
        file_object.write(repr(line) + '\n')
```

Comment: This does work, thank you very much.  I'm not exactly sure what repr() does.  I think it means representation right?  Is it sort of like escaping the entire string, so that no special metacharacters have any meaning?

Comment: @LeonardShelby: Yes, I believe it stands for representation. In Python, there’s two ways you can get a string out of an object: `str`, and `repr`. It’s not terribly straightforward to describe the difference, but `repr` generally is supposed to look more like Python code that could be evaluated to get the object again (I say *look more like*; it need not actually), whereas `str` just tries to get the object to be a string somehow, maybe in some display format.